# Scroll up in reload data every time

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(document).ready(function()
{
    j("#refresh").everyTime(3000, function(I)
    {
        j.ajax(
        {
          url: "refresh.php",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html)
          {
              j("#refresh").html(html);     

              var newscrollHeight = j("#refresh").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;

              j("#refresh").animate({scrollTop: newscrollHeight },      'normal'); //scrol otomatisnya                      

          }
        });
    });     
});
```

I want to scroll up my scroll but can't because #refresh reload every 3000. Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently,  have the success handler call the same method after 3 second if need be after you scrolled to the top.

Try something like this:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(document).ready(function()
{
      Refresh();
});     

function refresh()
{
    j.ajax(
    {
      url: "refresh.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html)
      {
          j("#refresh").html(html);     

        //  var newscrollHeight = j("#refresh").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
         // j("#refresh").animate({scrollTop: newscrollHeight },'normal'); //scrol otomatisnya   

          var div = $('#refresh');
          div.scrollTop(div.prop("scrollHeight") - 20);

          setTimeout(function()
          {
              Refresh();
          },3000);  // or how ever long     
      }
    });
}
```

UPDATE: I updated the scroll code

Comment: no working, i want to scroll on the botom otomaticly

Comment: I updated my answer try using $('#refresh').scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight") - 20);